# How do i execute these javascript module patterns?

Tags: javascript

I had learnt to structure modules using IIFEs. Simple example:

```
export test_module = (function{
    var name = "henry";
    var age = 26;
    var height ="6 monthe";

    var getHeight = function()
    {
        return height;
    }

    return{
        getHeight : getHeight
    }
}());
```

In another file I have

```
import {test_module} from './test_module'
```

I would like to learn to import and export IIFE modules using ECMAScript 6 module exports and imports. I installed Babel the transpiler. But when I export my module and try to import it in another file I get an error saying:

```
 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {text_module} from './test_module'
                                                                 ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
```

What is my problem ? Do I have a wrong syntax?

Comment: Unfortunately because of automatic semi-colon insertion, `return` doesn't work as expected when it's on its own line like you have it. `{ getHeight : getHeight }` will never be returned. You need to put the opening brace `{` on the same line as `return`.

Comment: Thanks alot for that @4castle

Comment: By the way, even if you don't personally use `class` syntax, it will still do some good to get comfortable with them. I avoid the `class` syntax myself (because I also avoid prototypical inheritance), but they're fairly common in the industry.

Comment: yah i understand that. I know how to use them..I just dont like them. I want a way around them. Creating good javascript modules without any classes thing or inheritance things and restrictions they bring

Comment: If you're not interested in any inheritance whatsoever, it might be that you prefer a [functional programming style](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/), which is a completely different approach to writing code in JS than OOP.

Comment: Thanks for hinting that.

Comment: Fyi There's a typo in the import statement. I don't see anything called "text_module" (notice the X).

Comment: Thanks alot for that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error, as Babel reports. Instead of

```
export test_module =
```

you must say

```
export const test_module =
```

Anyway, ES6 modules make the old IIFE-style "modules" obsolete (pretty much). Just write

```
// my-module.js

export function getHeight() {
    var name = "henry";
    var age = 26;
    var height = "6 monthe";

    return height;
}
```

Or, if you prefer

```
function getHeight() {
    var name = "henry";
    var age = 26;
    var height = "6 monthe";

    return height;
}

export { getHeight };
```

Then, when you want to use it:

```
import { getHeight } from './my-module';

getHeight();
```

or

```
import * as myModule from './my-module';

myModule.getHeight();
```

As for your rant about classes, I don't understand what it has to do with your question. If you don't like classes in ES6, then don't use them. Classes have nothing to do with ES6 modules, other than the obvious fact that like any other values classes can be exported and imported.

Comment: because Evvery example i see online . Uses classes\

Comment: Thanks though.. How can i strucure a full Module without any class things

Comment: Tho from the answer you gave i dont feel a module notion i feel like i just exported one function

Comment: You created a module named `my-module`, which includes an export called `getHeight`. As for classes, if you don't like them, and many people don't, then ignore the examples that use them, and find examples that don't. You don't need to "structure a module"; just write it, and export the things you want to export.